# Printing Turkish Characters in GUI

Tags: java, character-encoding, turkish

I have a Java project that connects to a C# program that prints Turkish words. Printing Turkish characters in C# using console is not causing any problems. However, the main issue is that when this C# program is called from Java, the Turkish characters are printed weirdly. 
What I would like to do is to get the output printed on console and reprint it using Java GUI without having any problems with Turkish characters.
I really appreciate any kind of help.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: I understand the problem has to do with encoding issues (transforming between bytes and chars) but could you be a little more specific in the way your Java program connects to your C# program? I think Java is sending Strings encoded differently than the expected things.

Comment: By example: Java sends "Wórd" encoded in ISO-8859-1 and it's 4 bytes. If C# decodes it in UTF-8 it will decode the byte corresponding to the ó in a bad way).

Comment: It is connected through a Process. And, the output is read using BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
   InputStreamReader(Process.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to be that the C# application is encoding its character data in one encoding while the Java application is decoding the data as another. Assuming Windows, it is possibly an ANSI/OEM mismatch.

You need to identify the encoding the C# application is emitting. In the Java application, read each byte and check its hex value. Check to see if the bytes are [Windows-1254](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305147.aspx), [OEM-857](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305163.aspx) or whatever and then decode them appropriately using a [reader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) with the appropriate [encoding](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).